# Setting margin-right in jQuery not working in IE11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11

[codepen](https://codepen.io/thrilom/pen/BaygPpr): `[https://codepen.io/thrilom/pen/BaygPpr][1]`

My code works in every browser I have tested except IE11. I have not gotten into Edge yet but I assume it will be the same issue. I have set

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

The jQuery simply takes the `margin-right` of the container and gives the other element a negative margin to suck it up to the far right of the viewport. HELP!

```js
(function($) {
  $(window).on("load resize", function() {
    var adjustMargin = $(".two-col-image__container").css('marginRight');
    $(".two-col-image__marginChange").css('marginRight', '-' + adjustMargin);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="container-fluid two-col-image" style="background: url(assets/images/about-bg@2x.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container two-col-image__container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-6 ml-auto d-flex align-items-center mt-4 mt-md-0 two-col-image__group">
            <div class="two-col-image__group-container">
              <h2 class="h6 two-col-image__title">HELLO WORLD</h2>
              <h3 class="h2 two-col-image__sub-title">ABOUT</h3>
              <p>More text</p>

              <p><a href="#">Scooter</p>
         <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-default"><span>learn more</span><img class="img-fluid btn-default__img"
           alt="Link Icon" src="assets/images/btn-icon.svg" /></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-6 two-col-image__image-group">
            <div class="two-col-image__marginChange">
              <img class="two-col-image__image" alt="About Cotton" class="img-fluid" src="assets/images/about-image-card@2x.png" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: We would need to see a working example of the problem, including HTML and CSS, in order to help you debug this.

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(adjustMargin)`? Been a while since I've worked with jQuery but I *think* that value is not what you think it is

Comment: @TylerRoper jQuery lets you use either the CSS property name or the JS `style` property name.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan TIL! Thanks Rory.

Comment: It takes the margin-right of the container and applies it to the other div as a negative margin. It works on all other browser.lol Sorry I will get the html here.

Comment: I had this before but was the same issue.

(function ($) {
    $(window).on("load resize", function () {

        var adjustMargin = $(".two-col-image__container").css('margin-right');

        $(".two-col-image__marginChange").css('margin-right', '-' + adjustMargin);
        
    });
})(jQuery);

Comment: I added the html now. Please let me know what else is needed. I am using

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: console.log = 322.5px
and the container computed styles is
.container = margin-right:322.5px;

This adjusts with the width of the viewport and the console.log adjust accordingly on Chrom, Chromium, FireFox and Safari so far my issue is IE

Comment: <div class="two-col-image__marginChange" style="margin-right: -322.5px;">

Comment: When I look at the computed styles in Chrome I get 325.5px When I look at computed styles in IE i see 0 for margin-left and margin-right. Bootstrap centers the container automatically how else can I do this in IE?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue using the code you providing. I `console.log` the `adjustMargin` and they're `0px` in IE and Chrome. You could check [the sample](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GBJ8X51LO3DZ) I use. The issue might related with the other codes in your app and could you please provide [a minimal sample which can reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the issue?

Comment: I resolved this by removing all jQuery and sticking with css to do this. Seems to be a way better option for all browser support:

```width: calc(50vw - #{$grid-gutter-width/2});```

Comment: You could put your solution as an answer and mark it as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by removing all jQuery and sticking with css to do this. Seems to be a way better option for all browser support: `width: calc(50vw - #{$grid-gutter-width/2});`